# Ubuntu can't shutdown / log out properly

Tags: 14.04, kernel, shutdown

When I want to shutdown or log out my laptop it won't and will show a black screen with some messages in it.

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer deferences at   (null)`
```

and some other messages. I can't go to setting . I can't find bluetooth and other problems that I didn't have discover.

Answer (score 0):

That indicates a BUG in the kernel or a hardware issue. It's probably a kernel panic. You can tell if it's a kernel panic sometimes as the capslock light will usually blink.

If that's the case, force the reboot. If you are lucky you may be asked to file a bug on the kernel. If you aren't asked to do so by the system after the reboot, can manually file a bug with instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs).

Comment: when I want to do that I got a message like this`The problem cannot be reported:

This is not an official Ubuntu package. Please remove any third party package and try again. `

Comment: If I do that I have to wait one year and somebody fix that problem

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your current kernel:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then reboot.

If the problem isn't solved, then "force shutdown" with the shutdown button, and start the system with an older kernel in the advanced start menu of grub.

Comment: I did that but nothing happened.

Comment: Aptitude suggest some solution ?!

Comment: what do you mean ? what is aptitude

Comment: I'm confused With another post.

Comment: Hello m3asmi, please take a look at the edit I made, you wrote a little too fast and mispelled your command line.